# PHP array of string pick 2 elements only

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of string. Each string is a filename. Each file name is either an image ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png') or a video/audio ('.mp4', '.mov', '.flv', '.mp3').
Example :
`$files [] = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.mp4', 'file3.mov', 'file4.flv', 'file5.png'];`

How can I create a new array from the `$files` array with two filenames only of different type e.g. 1 video and 1 image like :
`['file1.jpg', 'file3.mov']` or `['file1.jpg', 'file2.mp4']`

Comment: `$files [][0] = ["file1.jpg", "file3.mov"]; $files [][0] = ["file1.jpg", "file2.mp4"]; `

Comment: You mean like a random one of each?

Comment: @mamesaye, I did not understand your question clearly, so I just posted a result. What is your input and what is your expected output? What is your current code? If you want to clarify image and Video in 1 array together, you must define and 2 arrays first. 1 is for image types (png, gif, jpeg, jpg) and 1 for video (mp4, mov,...). Then you do the loop for input array, and look up in the 2 array of file types for clarify for result array. (You got 724 reputation, so I think you got enough experience in PHP)

Comment: @NgocNam: I don't understand, can you explain please?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: yes it is random you don't know the order. All I know is that it has  filenames of videos and audios.

Comment: @NgocNam: thanks for the explanation. I just did not know how to approach it. it's been a long day. and I am pretty new to PHP but is using other language.

Comment: @mamesaye, OK, I will make a sample for you, please wait for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the different types of extensions you're looking for.

```
$extension_types = [
    'image' => ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
    'video' => ['mp4', 'mov', 'flv', 'mp3']
];
```

Then, for each of those types, iterate the files array until you find a file with one of the extensions for it. Add that to your result and go on to the next type.

```
foreach ($extension_types as $type => $extensions) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $extensions)) {
            $result[] = $file;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will get the first element in the `$files` array for each extension type.

Comment: Mamesaye is new in PHP, I think you should explain more for his understanding.

Comment: @NgocNam I appreciate the feedback. Which part do you think needs more explanation? I didn't explain what in_array and pathinfo do. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Don't Panic: thanks but I will end up with more than 2 files (1 video and 1 image) in my new array ... but I just want 2.

Comment: I understand the `in_array` but I am googling `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`.  :)

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I meant you should explain the process of your code. But mameyase understood, so it is OK.

Comment: @mamesaye the `break;` keeps it from adding more than one of each type. As soon as it adds one, the inner foreach loop stops.

Comment: @mamesaye `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` it will return the extension of a file. Like "file1.jpg" -> 'jpg'. Just it.

Comment: @NgocNam I definitely agree with adding explanation to answers. Code-only answers really bug me. But I usually keep the explanation concise initially and edit the answer to expand on it if someone has further questions. Just enough to (in my estimation) get the point across.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I agree. :)